# Copy Missing Data from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using the following code to go through two workbooks and compare column E. If there is data missing in wb1 column E to copy the missing data from wb2 column E. Simple as that but because I have between 1k to 4k rows in wb1 this makes it so slow. I wait 20 seconds sometimes until the operation is finalised.

I wonder if you know a better way that I should follow to achieve a faster response.

```
Sub AddMissing()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Dim lrow1 As Long
Dim lrow2 As Long

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim ValueChk As Boolean


Set wb1 = Workbooks("Testbook1.xlsx") 'Main workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Testbook2.xlsx") 'Second workbook

Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")

lrow1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
lrow2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To lrow2
    
    For j = 2 To lrow1
        If ws1.Cells(j, 5) = ws2.Cells(i, 5) Then
            ValueChk = True
            GoTo Nexti
        End If
    Next j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested For loop and reading cells (`Cells(..)`) can be time-consuming, which may contribute to the slow performance.

Changes:

- Load data from Col E into array
- Utilizing a `Dictionary` object to store data provides a more efficient way to match data with another workbook.
- Write missing data into worksheet all at once.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AddMissing()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lrow1 As Long
    Dim lrow2 As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim ValueChk As Boolean
    Dim k As Long, objDic As Object
    Dim arrData1, arrData2, arrRes()
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("Testbook1.xlsx") 'Main workbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Testbook2.xlsx") 'Second workbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lrow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    lrow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Load data into array
    arrData1 = ws1.Range("E1:E" & lrow1)
    arrData2 = ws2.Range("E1:E" & lrow2)
    ReDim arrRes(1 To lrow2, 1 To 1)
    ' Load data from ws1 into Dict
    For i = 2 To lrow1
        objDic(arrData1(i, 1)) = ""
    Next i
    j = 1
    ' Comparing data w/ ws2
    For i = 2 To lrow2
        If Not objDic.exists(arrData2(i, 1)) Then
            ' Store missing data
            arrRes(j, 1) = arrData2(i, 1)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    ' Append missing data to ws1
    If j > 1 Then
        ws1.Cells(lrow1 + 1, "E").Resize(j - 1, 1).Value = arrRes
    End If
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)